# jquery mobile web app external HTML page open in web app browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, jquery-mobile

I created a jquery mobile web app and on one of the buttons it links to an .HTML file. When I add the web app to my home screen and tap that button it opens the .HTML page in safari instead of staying within the app. I did some research online and came across this file but I still can't get it to work. Any ideas how to address this?

https://github.com/mrmoses/jQuery.stayInWebApp

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Comment: no nothing. Pages render as fine with the expect for the one that has the external link, that still opens up safari. I'll keep experimenting with it.

Comment: It's an anchor link? Share all your code that applies to this. Your HTML and JS

Comment: FYI - my code has nothing to do with the plug-in your mention. Remove that plug-in (may be conflicting), and make sure my code is as below. Then place my script right before the closing body tag. Note the `<script/>` tag and document ready wrappers I used. In addition, make sure you clear the cache of the web app by manually closing the app and restarting (once the new code has been uploaded to your dev server)

Comment: I have an UL list and 4 out of the 5 buttons I have are anchor links. One button goes out to an .html file.

http://production.elpasotimes.net/LasCrucesCountryFestival/

You can view the source here. Thank you for the help.

Comment: I see..it's because you're using `hash` tags as a `href`. try putting the base url in the `href`. For example, like so: `production.elpasotimes.net/LasCrucesCountryFestival/#direc`

Comment: Ummmm.... The hash tags are intended for the jquery pages that are within the index.html, if i remove the hash tag from #direc then the button to that won't work. Maybe i am misunderstanding you...

Comment: You're not removing the hash tag..it still exists at the end of the URL. Just give it a test...likely won't work. As it looks like jQuery mobile is using it. There may be a conflict.

Comment: Once I save the web app to the home screen and then launch the app from there the buttons do not function. The buttons do function if I use the web app in safari.

Comment: Not sure man...my script dons't work with hashtags

Comment: Its cool man. It's Friday and going to catch a beer, maybe after a few drinks I'll figure this out. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Pls add some html/js code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I use...applies to all `anchors`. To make a long story short, it's disabling each anchors default behaviour, grabbing the clicked anchor's `href`, and then using js to open the link within the web-app. Applied to mobile devices only.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    // prevent anchor links from opening in safari, web-app fix
    if (("standalone" in window.navigator) && window.navigator.standalone) {
        // For iOS Apps
        $('a').on('touchend click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(); return false;
            var new_location = $(this).attr('href');
            if (new_location != undefined && new_location.substr(0, 1) != '#' && $(this).attr('data-method') == undefined) {
                window.location = new_location;
            }
        });
    }
});
</script>
```